# Creating repeating set from another column in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, create-table, repeat, rep

Using these dataset:

```
[A]
100
200
300

[B]
A
B
C
```

I would like to make this column:

```
[A]   [B]
100    A
100    B
100    C
200    A
200    B
200    C
300    A
300    B
300    C
```

I would like to use rep function in R, but it does not work.
How do I create this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rep()` as follows

```
data.frame(A=rep(c(100,200,300), c(3,3,3)),
               B=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3))
```

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to generalize the answer beyond the exact example. In this instance, the use of 3. Here, you could do `rep(A, each=length(B))` and `rep(B, length(A))`.

Comment: Thnx for tip, will do

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
d1 <- expand.grid(A = df1$A, B = df1$B)
```

---

Or with `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(A= df1$A, B= df1$B)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(100, 200, 300), B = LETTERS[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```